# Alignment issues

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment, resume

I'm new to LaTeX and was using it to build my resume for my masters applications.
I need the entries for Languages and Databases to be left-aligned (with each other, the way Languages and Databases are). Right now they are placed haphazardly.
This is the code snippet right now.

```
\textbf{Languages}
\hspace{0.5cm}
STATA, Python

\vspace{0.1cm}

\textbf{Databases}
\hspace{0.5cm}
WRDS, Prowess
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You probably want to use a table for this. See https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08 for a short tutorial.

Comment: [Welcome to Tex.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) -- it is very hard to answer this question!  There are many ways to get text to line up properly, but it is impossible to recommend one without knowing some more context.  Can you please try to expand your snippet into a complete  [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the problem?

Comment: And having noted the above, you might try something like this:  `\makebox[2cm][l]{\textbf{Languages}} STATA, Python`

Comment: @Thruston's suggestion worked. Thanks a bunch, people!